# move uploaded file into folder in php

Tags: php, mysql

I used below code to update the image into table, it is updating the image fine, but while retriving the images the path is displaying correctly, but the image is not displaying in the page.please gudie me with the above

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("jpg","png","gif");      
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"C:\wamp\www\Mr.bazaar\images\ ".$file_name);
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}


        $a=$_POST['pids'];
        echo $a;
        $b=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo $b;
        $qry1=mysql_query("update brand set image='$b' where brand='$a'");

        if($qry1)
        echo "<script>alert('Your image Sucessgully Uploaded.');</script>"; 
        else
        echo "<script>alert('try again');</script>";
```

I used the below the code to display the image in the page, but it is not displaying in the page

```
$result = mysql_query("select b_id,brand,image from brand"); 

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                    // Print out the contents of each row into a table

                    echo '<tr>';

                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $row['brand'];
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo '<img height="30" width="60" src=../../images/';
                    echo $row['image'];
                    echo '>';

                    echo '</td>';


                }
```

Comment: is your image uploading in given path ?

Comment: @vijay..where you are showing the image. where is the code for it?

Comment: You have to set the permission of folder images to 777 ie, give full permission to the folder and check once.

Comment: how can i give the permission in localhost

Comment: Right click on the images folder and you can see the properties option in which there Permissions setting. There you have to set all permissions to Create and delete files.

Comment: @vijay: You should **absolutely** read this: [PHP Image Upload Security: How Not to Do It](http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to image in your last code. Suppose, the loop should look like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $product = $row['brand'];
  $image = $row['image'];
  echo "<option value=\"$product\">$image</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view there are two mistakes.

1. First check in upload directory if files are actually being uploaded.
   if file are not being uploaded 
   then give **relative path to upload directory in move_uploaded_file function**  i.e. path should look   like  **"../../upload_directory"** and not like "c:/somefolder/"  nor like "http://example.com/abs".
2. Second error is at your image source declaration

   `src=../../images/';
   echo $row['image'];
   echo '>';`

   Here you are missing double quotes i.e ("") after src. It should be like

   `src="../../images/';
   echo $row['image'];
   echo '">';`

Please note the double quotes (") after  = sign in first line and before angular brackets > in last line.

Hope after correcting above two error your code should work fine.

Comment: but the page of the image shows in the view source of the browser

Comment: vijay are are able to see uploaded file in your uploads directory i.e C:\wamp\www\Mr.bazaar\images\ after uploading files?